# How to use node_modules that are not in my directory in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native

I have project folders like `project/nativeApp`, where `nativeApp` is the folder where the react native project resides. I want to use npm libraries, that are normally required like so `const React = require('react')`.

Thing is, I want to have only one `package.json` and `node_modules/` for the whole project in the `project` folder so only one `npm install` is needed. How do I require libraries that are "one level up" in my file system?